# What function in base R can be considered equivalent to %>% (pipes)?

Tags: r

I have a `df_1`:

```
set.seed(1)

df_1 <- data.frame(
  x = replicate(2, runif(30, 20, 100)), 
  y = sample(1:3, 30, replace = TRUE)
)
```

I use `tidyverse` with `pipes`:

```
df_1 %>% 
  select(1, 3) %>% 
  group_by(y) %>% 
  slice(1:2)
```

How does all this in `base R` with `%>%`, subset functions, like `[]` and `aggregate`?

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re asking but (a) `%>%` isn’t a subset function, and (b) there’s no equivalent to `%>%` in base R (but it’s trivial to write your own).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `by`

```
do.call(rbind, by(df_1[c(1, 3)], df_1$y, head, 2))
#         x.1 y
#1.2 49.76991 1
#1.4 92.65662 1
#2.3 65.82827 2
#2.5 36.13455 2
#3.1 41.24069 3
#3.8 72.86382 3
```